# java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider for Microsoft time-zones

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, iana

I am coding against an external API that returns what appear to be windows time-zone descriptions as strings e.g. "Romance Standard Time", and I need to parse these into java `ZoneId`s or offsets. A list of these values is available [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/973627/microsoft-time-zone-index-values).

The `java.time.ZoneId` documentation states:

> Time-zone rules are defined by governments and change frequently.
>   There are a number of organizations, known here as groups, that
>   monitor time-zone changes and collate them. The default group is the
>   IANA Time Zone Database (TZDB). Other organizations include IATA (the
>   airline industry body) **and Microsoft**.

So my question is, does there exist a public implementation of `java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider` from Microsoft as alluded to in the javadoc?

I'm aware that there is a relationship between the Microsoft timezones and the standard IANA TZDB, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600085/missing-microsoft-time-zones). But what I want to know is whether there exists a standard implemenation of `ZoneRulesProvider` that I can pass in as a property, as described in the the javadoc:

> If the system property java.time.zone.DefaultZoneRulesProvider is
>   defined then it is taken to be the fully-qualified name of a concrete
>   ZoneRulesProvider class to be loaded as the default provider, using
>   the system class loader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java docs are correct that IANA, IATA, and Microsoft are sources of time zone information.  However, though it may be possible for a `ZoneRulesProvider` to be created for each, to the best of my knowledge I don't believe there are any standard `ZoneRulesProvider` implementations for anything other than IANA data.  One could probably be written, if one was so inclined.

There is a reasonable solution though.  As the other question you linked to mentioned, time zone mappings between IANA and Microsoft are maintained through the [windowsZones.xml file in the Unicode CLDR](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).  You can use this data to translate from the Microsoft time zone ID returned by the external API, to an IANA time zone name.   You can use it directly, or you can take a dependency on a library that provides this functionality for you.  A good library choice would be [*International Components for Unicode (ICU)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode),  via the [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/) implementation found on the [project page](http://site.icu-project.org/).  It's `getIDForWindowsID` method ([docs here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/TimeZone.html#getIDForWindowsID-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)) uses the CLDR data to provide the translation.

Alternatively, if you have any influence over the external API, chances are if it's returning Microsoft time zone IDs that it is built using .NET.  If so, you could encourage the developers of that API to return a standard IANA time zone ID in their API result (perhaps as a secondary field if they are concerned about compatibility).   My open source [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library is appropriate for this purpose, and also uses the same CLDR data.

Note that IANA time zone IDs are already in place in several areas at Microsoft, including .NET Core on Linux/MacOS, .NET Framework via libraries such as Noda Time and others, Universal Windows Platform (UWP) applications, and a few others.  The "Microsoft time zones" are an artifact of history, going back to the earliest days of Windows NT.  Developers should generally be encouraged to use IANA time zone IDs, rather than Microsoft time zones, especially in external-facing APIs for interoperability with non-Windows systems.  More on Microsoft time zones can be found in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Also - be aware that the page you linked to with the list of Microsoft time zones is almost a decade old, and is around for legacy purposes.  The index columns was only ever used on Windows CE platforms, and several of those time zones no longer exist.  We no longer publish a list of these time zones as a static web page, because the data changes too frequently.  You can always get a list from any Windows computer via the command `TZUTIL /L`, or by calling `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` in .NET or Powershell, or by examining the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.

Full Disclosure: I help maintain the time zones at Microsoft, as well as several open source time zone libraries for .NET.

Comment: By the way, the CLDR data has been bundled with Java, at least with the OpenJDK-based implementations, since Java 8. [Used by default in Java 9](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252) and later. I do not know if this Microsoft-mapping would be available without adding the ICU4J library or not.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.  But yeah, probably not useful unless it exposes a method like `getIDForWindowsID`

Comment: @MattJohnson I ended up implementing a mapping from the CLDR xml, the same as you suggested - this isn't too complicated. However thre are two problem: 1) it is not a bijection; for a single windows tz there may be one or more IANA timezones. 2) It is only for a single point in time (present). This means the mappings for today may not necessarily be the same mappings as 50 years ago. That's why I was looking for an official implementation of the java class.

Comment: On point 1, you are correct. That is why cldr tracks a general mapping (indicated by 001) and a more specific territory mapping for when the territory is known. On point 2, the databases didn't exist 50 years ago. Yes, the mappings change over time, as do time zones. But they are generally intended to be the best currently known mapping, for all points in time. In other words, you don't need a specific point in time to figure out which mapping to use.  It is indeed important to keep updated with the changes, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I found these threads relevant to your question although the questions themselves don't seem to be relevant. The accepted answers to these questions may shed a light to your question:

[Extremely slow parsing of time zone with the new java.time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34374464/extremely-slow-parsing-of-time-zone-with-the-new-java-time-api/34376638#34376638)

[Java doesn't have information about all IANA time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592878/java-doesnt-have-information-about-all-iana-time-zones/45595686#45595686)

It seems that it could be a good idea to subclass ZoneRulesProvider and provide your customized implementation...

For your question, I tried to search online and did not find ZoneRulesProvider implementation from Microsoft...