# get timezone supported by microsoft using offset in java

Tags: java, timezone, microsoft-graph-api

In my current project, I want to use [FindMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API from Microsoft Graph API. In sample request the time slot using time zone that supported by Microsoft ([additional dateTimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0), [default time zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11)). My current problem is how I get the time zone that supported by Microsoft using string offset like this `"+07:00"` in Java ?.

For example my function gets the argument `"+07:00"`, I want this function to return the string `"SE Asia Standard Time"`.

Comment: You may find some useful information here, as a starting point: [java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider for Microsoft time-zones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52857334/12567365) and in similar questions.

Comment: Also related: [java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider for Microsoft time-zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857334/java-time-zone-zonerulesprovider-for-microsoft-time-zones) with [a very knowledgable answer by Matt Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860643/5772882)